# Error: Error parsing body of the with expression

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm making a web development course with a lot of webpack dependencies, express.js and pug.js for now. I am stuck when I install pug.js, it's not rendered on the browser and I receive this error, both in the browser and in the terminal:

```
Error: Error parsing body of the with expression
    at addWith (C:\Users\Name\Desktop\building-an-immersive-creative-website-from-scratch-without-frameworks\floema\node_modules\with\lib\index.js:50:29)
    at Compiler.compile (C:\Users\Name\Desktop\building-an-immersive-creative-website-from-scratch-without-frameworks\floema\node_modules\pug-code-gen\index.js:139:12)
    at generateCode (C:\Users\Name\Desktop\building-an-immersive-creative-website-from-scratch-without-frameworks\floema\node_modules\pug-code-gen\index.js:32:37)
    at compileBody (C:\Users\Name\Desktop\building-an-immersive-creative-website-from-scratch-without-frameworks\floema\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:199:74)
    at Object.exports.compile (C:\Users\Name\Desktop\building-an-immersive-creative-website-from-scratch-without-frameworks\floema\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:269:16)
    at handleTemplateCache (C:\Users\Name\Desktop\building-an-immersive-creative-website-from-scratch-without-frameworks\floema\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:242:25)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (C:\Users\Name\Desktop\building-an-immersive-creative-website-from-scratch-without-frameworks\floema\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:454:10)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (C:\Users\Name\Desktop\building-an-immersive-creative-website-from-scratch-without-frameworks\floema\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:444:21)
    at View.exports.__express [as engine] (C:\Users\Name\Desktop\building-an-immersive-creative-website-from-scratch-without-frameworks\floema\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:493:11)
    at View.render (C:\Users\Name\Desktop\building-an-immersive-creative-website-from-scratch-without-frameworks\floema\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
```

I am very stuck with that 'cause nobody in the course has the same error and I don't know how to solve it. I put also the code from app.js file

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
const port = 3000

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'pug')

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {
    meta: {
      data: {
        title: 'Floema',
        description: 'Metadata'
      }
    }
  })
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

The pug file is at the beginning

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    meta(charset="UTF-8")
    meta(name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")

    base(href="/")

    title Floema

    meta(name="description" content="Floema beautiful jewlery.")

    link(rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png")
    link(rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png")
    link(rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png")
    link(rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest")
    link(rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pnned-tab.svg" color:"#ff3a00")
    meta(name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#f4d8cc")
    meta(name="theme-color" content="#f4d8cc")

    meta(property="og:type" content="website")
    meta(property="og:title" content=meta.data.title)
    meta(property="og:description" content=meta.data.description)
    meta(property="og:image" content=meta.data.image ? meta.data.image.url : '')

    meta(name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image")
    meta(name="twitter:title" content=meta.data.title)
    meta(name="twitter:description" content=meta.data.description)
    meta(name="twitter:image" content=meta.data.image ? meta.data.image.url : '')

    link(href="main.css" rel="stylesheet")

  body
    .preloader
      p.preloader__text
        | The surprise of what is possible
        | to make with a simple
        | and thin thread.

      .preloader__number 0%
```

I need you need something else feel free to ask me, I really want to continue the course.
Thanks
Carlo

Comment: Do you have the pug package installed?

Comment: Took me a while, but in hindsight the colors are making it obvious. In your mask-icon link, you have `color:"#ff3a00"` instead of `color="#ff3a00"`

Comment: Hi @ChrisG you have definitely solved my problem, thank you very much

Comment: Hi @lkdemm Yes pug is installed, thanks for your comment :) I solve the problem